# I'd like to configure autoaudiosink

Tags: gstreamer

Many simple programs use gstreamer for handling media files. And in doing so they define the output-device to be "autoaudiosink". This doesn't work for me since this forces the use of HDMI-sound output which I do not have attached to my computer. I tried patching such a program with `alsasink device=hw:1,0` in place of `autoaudiosink`, but this produced an error (and the program isn't able to tell me which error it is). I suspect gstreamer library does not like spaces in its library-function-parameters.

My new idea is to maybe delete the hdmi-driver from my installation? 
Or is there some other way to prevent autoaudiosink to choose that?

What is the correct way in a program using the gstreamer library to express above idea of hard-coding my device? For example in http://github.com/gkarsay/parlatype.git my patch says

```
--- parlatype-1.5.2/libparlatype/src/pt-player.c        2017-08-03 14:58:24.000000000 +0200
+++ parlatype-1.5.2.new/libparlatype/src/pt-player.c    2019-07-18 10:00:49.189372451 +0200
@@ -1472,7 +1472,7 @@
        player->priv->play = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin",       "play");
        scaletempo         = gst_element_factory_make ("scaletempo",    "tempo");
        capsfilter         = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter",    "audiofilter");
-       audiosink          = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audiosink");
+       audiosink          = gst_element_factory_make ("alsasink device=hw:1,0", "audiosink");

        /* checks */
 #if GST_CHECK_VERSION(1,3,0)
```

in version 1.5.2, and the program fails to create a player-object (and instead crashes while creating a message-box for displaying the error)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `g_object_set()` to set properties on elements. Simply instantiate the element:

```
audiosink          = gst_element_factory_make ("alsasink", "audiosink");
```

and then set it's property:

```
g_object_set(audiosink, "device", "hw:1,0", NULL);
```